# Vue3 Router duplicated component

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I'm creating an app using Vue3js and vue-router.

When the app is created, I get my first component duplicated.

My `App.vue` component is this:

```
<template>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md  fixed-top">
        <div class="menu-izq">
            <router-link id="logo" class="menu-item" to="/">COVELESS</router-link>
            <router-link class="menu-item" v-if="!this.userLogged" to="/login">Login</router-link>
            <router-link class="menu-item" v-if="this.userLogged" to="/canvas">Canvas</router-link>
            <router-link class="menu-item" v-if="this.userLogged" to="/dashboard">Dashboard</router-link>
        </div>
        <div class="menu-dcha">
            <router-link class="menu-item" v-if="this.userLogged" v-on:click="vaciarStorage()" to="/login">Logout
            </router-link>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <router-view></router-view>
</div>
```

My `router.js` file is this

```
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from 

'vue-router'
import LoginMenu from './components/LoginMenu.vue'
import AllElement from './components/AllElement.vue'
import Dashboard from './components/Dashboard.vue'
import App from './App.vue'

const routes = [
    {
        path: '/',
        name: 'Home',
        component: App
    },
    {
        path: '/login',
        name: 'Login',
        component: LoginMenu
    },
    {
        path: '/canvas',
        name: 'Canvas',
        component: AllElement
    },
    {
        path: '/dashboard',
        name: 'Dashboard',
        component: Dashboard
    }
]

const history = createWebHistory();

const router = createRouter({
    history,
    routes,
});

export default router
```

And my `app.js` file is this

```
import './bootstrap';

import { createApp } from 'vue/dist/vue.esm-bundler'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'

createApp(App).use(router).mount('#app');
```

So when the App component is mounted on #app, the navbar gets duplicated because it is mounting another App component at "/" path (I guess because it is defined at router.js like that). But if I remove the

```
    {
        path: '/',
        name: 'Home',
        component: App
    }
```

route, then I'm never navigating to the index.

Here you can see both the App components.

[image]

Comment: I fixed it by creating a Home view and binding it to "/" path on the route.js file, by the way I don't know if that's the proper way of doing it, would be fine some feedback anyways

Comment: can you also post template of the view that is displaying duplicate

Comment: it was the App.vue view which was displaying duplicated

Comment: @AlvaroNavarrete Yes, that was the solution actually. The problem was that you were using App.vue as the component in one of your paths. So App.vue was render inside App.vue.